# 2 action em um botão submit?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou montando um formulário onde envia os dados para meu banco de dados, só que tipo nesse formulário queria executar ***2*** `actions` em um botão `submit` só que no caso `actions` são  `id="ajax_form"` e `id="step2Button"`.

Como posso executar as duas em meu codigo, a ajax manda o formulário e a step2, continua o formulário uma segunda parte?

***Esta é a id="ajax_form"***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "processar.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    alert( data );
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

***E esta é a id="step2Button***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    location();
    $('#step2Button').click(function(){
           if($('#username').val()==""){
               swal("Error", "Nome de usuario requerido!", "error")
           }
           if($('#senha').val()==""){
               swal("Error", "Senha requerida!", "error")
           }
           else{
               $('#step1').fadeOut(500,function(){
                   $('#step2').fadeIn(500);
               });
           }

           return false;
   });
```

Essa de cima, continua no mesmo formulário, tipo uma segunda parte do formulário após enviar a primeira..

Comment: é só criar uma função (`function`) e chamar as duas ações.

Comment: Desculpa Virgilio, tentei de muitas formas poderia me ajudar com o codigo?

Comment: Qual é a sequencia de execução

Comment: Primeiro envia o ajax_form depois step2Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelos comentários seria, basicamente seria isso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function()
        {
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "processar.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    alert( data );
                    fs_click_step2();
                }               
            });
          return false;
        });
    });

    $('#step2Button').click(function(){
       fs_click_step2();
    });

    function fs_click_step2()
    {
        if($('#username').val()==""){
           swal("Error", "Nome de usuario requerido!", "error")
        }
        if($('#senha').val()==""){
           swal("Error", "Senha requerida!", "error")
        }
        else{
           $('#step1').fadeOut(500,function(){
               $('#step2').fadeIn(500);
           });
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Como vai acontecer, primeiro é executado `ajax_form` e a for com sucesso é executado o `step2Button`.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou resolvido já!